How to give a user a role in a discord server using Discord API endpoints and python requests library
I am trying to provide a user with a role using Discord API Endpoints and python requests library
I have tried using the function below to give a user a role in my discord server using the Discord API Guild endpoint as seen:
def give_role(guild_id,user_id,role_id):
    url = f"https://discord.com/api/guilds/{guild_id}/members/{user_id}/roles/{role_id}"
    
    data = {
        "type": 4,
        "data": {
        }
    }
    response = requests.put(url, json=data)
    print(response)

I get "<Response [401]>" from the print(response) function. I am expecting to get a "<Response[204]>" message and the user to be given the role

If you're using requests, then don't have discord.py as a tag

I heavily recommend not programming a bot with requests as it's extremely tedious unless you use a library

As per the error code your getting: 401 your request lacks the relevant credentials for authentication.
You should add the relevant authorization Header to your request.
response = requests.put(
           url, 
           json=data,
           headers ={ 'Authorization':'AUTH_TYPE YOUR_TOKEN' })
           #replace AUTH_TYPE and YOUR_TOKEN with aproppiate values

Following Discord API's docs on auth, you can register an app and acquire either a bot token or a OAuth2 bearer token to that effect.
